# Why is my second subButton not working?

Tags: c#, asp.net

This web page create controls. 
First control "Parent"
Second control "child". Child button creates by parent. But i have one problem, Page doesn't respond child event(((

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
    namespace WebApplication14
    {
        public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
        {
            private Button[] buttons = new Button[256];
            protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
```

#### Maybe i have a problem with this section???

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) // Create 10 buttons
                {
                    buttons[i] = new Button(); // New button
                    buttons[i].ID = "Button" + i; // Button id
                    buttons[i].Text = "Button " + i; // Button text
```

#### I don't know why this event not work propertly

```
                buttons[i].Click += (c, cArgs) => //Set Event
                    {
                        TextBox1.Text += "Hi"; //Doesn't show me result.Why???
                    };
            }
            int val = 0;
            Button b = new Button(); // Create new button
            b.ID = "BT1"; // Set button id "BT1"
            b.Text = "Click"; // Set on button text
            form1.Controls.Add(b); // add this button to form1
            b.Click += (k, kArgs) => // Give this button event with parameters
                {
                    val = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text); // Convert value of TextBox1  to int32 and set this value to variable "val"
                    form1.Controls.Add(buttons[val]); // Add subButton by value seted on variable "Val"
                };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: At first glance, `buttons[i].OnClientClick = "ButtonClick('" + buttons[i].ClientID + "')";` looks invalid.

Comment: a Web application is not winforms. there's no such thing as "handling a button click event" in C# code in a Web application.

Comment: instead you can use grid template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that it is best to have all UI objects and their events bound/added to the form at the beginning before the page is completely loaded (Page_Load), preferably at page initialization (Page_Init). Your current approach doesn’t bind the button's click event correctly because it’s happening after Page_Load after a click event occurs on button 'b'. To alleviate this, you should add ALL UI objects during Page_Init or if you must Page_Load BUT you can control their visibility instead. This way you can guarantee that all objects have their events bound to the form correctly:

**C# Code-Behind:**

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) // Create 10 buttons
      {
          buttons[i] = new Button(); // New button
          buttons[i].ID = "Button" + i; // Button id
          buttons[i].Text = "Button " + i; // Button text

          buttons[i].Click += (c, cArgs) => //Set Event
          {
             TextBox1.Text += "Hi";
          };

          buttons[i].Visible = false; // Set visibility to false
          form1.Controls.Add(buttons[i]); // Add button to form1
      }

      int val = 0;
      Button b = new Button(); // Create new button
      b.ID = "BT1"; // Set button id "BT1"
      b.Text = "Click"; // Set on button text
      form1.Controls.Add(b); // add this button to form1
      b.Click += (k, kArgs) => // Give this button event with parameters
      {
          val = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text); // Convert value of TextBox1  to int32 and set this value to variable "val"
          buttons[val].Visible = true; // Set visibility to true
      };
  }
```